# Adding to a variable determined by a function

Tags: python, function, variables

I have

```
random.choice([clas, elve, volcan, atl, fro, dark, terr, barb]) += 1
```

where I want the random function to pick a variable out of the 8 that are listed, and then I want to add 1 to that variable.

I get the can't assign to function call error when I try to do that because I can't add a value to the random function.  How do I make it so python adds 1 to the variable that the function returns?

I was thinking I could do it like:

```
rand_return = random.choice([clas, elve, volcan, atl, fro, dark, terr, barb])
rand_return += 1
```

But then instead of adding a value to one of the 8 variables in the original list, I create a new variable and just start messing with that, rather than editing the variable originally picked by the random function.

Comment: You could store your values in a list.  Choose an index then update the list indexed by the chosen value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `random.choice` choose from a list of strings that represent the name of the variable, and then use `globals()` (which returns a dictionary of all global names, including variables) to update the variable , Example -

```
rand_return = random.choice(['clas', 'elve', 'volcan', 'atl', 'fro', 'dark', 'terr', 'barb'])
gbl = globals()
gbl[rand_return] += 1
```

Shortened version -

```
globals()[random.choice(['clas', 'elve', 'volcan', 'atl', 'fro', 'dark', 'terr', 'barb'])] += 1
```

Comment: Just tried that, and I get an error I don't understand.  line 52, in <module>
    globals[random.choice(['clas', 'elve', 'volcan', 'atl', 'fro', 'dark', 'terr', 'barb'])] += 1
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: In the shortened version there is a function call i had missed, updated it, try that.

Comment: This is a right answer, but I think you should suggest a better approach as well. Personally, and I think that many will agree with me, this solution should be discouraged and instead use a list or dictionaries.

Comment: @NiklasR If you have a better answer, please post it.

Comment: @anand-s-kumar just did, had to wait a few minutes before it would let me.